# Python - While loop store min value

Tags: numpy, while-loop

I would like to store the minimum value during a while loop because of sometimes i cant converge and my value continues to fluctuate...
But i dont know how to store this minimum value met during the loop...

```
while np.abs(dX) > 2.:
  x0_corr = x0 + dX
  y0_corr = y0 
...
dX = ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a minValue var (outside your while loop), then each loop you can set it to the current minumum using

```
minValue = min(minValue, currentValue)
```

Thus it always maintains the minimum value seen so far.

[ If you don't know an initial value for minValue, you might need to initialise minValue to `None` and have some first time code in the loop like so:

```
if minValue == None:
    minValue = currentValue
else
    minValue = min(minValue, currentValue)
```

]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer: you can also initialize the minValue with lowest possible value, so you can skip this comparison in the loop:

`if minValue == None:
    minValue = currentValue`